# Have rest framework return null when response is None

Tags: django-rest-framework

My understanding is that rest framework 3's

```
Response(None)
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
Response()
```

, where the (JSON) result is an empty response body, rather than `null`. An empty response would translate to a JavaScript `undefined` rather than `null`, which is incorrect. So, should I insist on `null` being returned, I cannot do:

```
Response('null')
```

because that is understandably serialised to `"null"`. So, in order to yield an actual `null` in the response, I must hack up a custom renderer that indiscriminately returns a JSON dump of its data:

```
class PlainTextRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/json'
    format = 'json'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        import json
        return json.dumps(data)

renderer_classes = (PlainTextRenderer,)
```

This seems too hacky to be true. Although the renderer does work, am I missing something much simpler?

Comment: I'd return an empty body with status 204 No Content https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5

Comment: I *want* the response body to contain `null`. 204 No Content does the opposite of providing a response body.

Comment: this is actually crazy. Why do they have a special case for `None` like this. Empty string is not even valid json. Failure. :-/